# HTML Table into Multi-Series Chart

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Is there any way to generate automatically from html table to multi-series chart? Either using javascript or jquery?
Here's my sample of table

```
| Category |    YYYY    |   YYYY   |   YYYY   |
| Asset    | 1,500.00   | 3,590.00 | 5,000.00 |
| Revenue  | 2,560.00   | 6,700.90 | 4,900.00 |
| Others   | 3,000.00   | 4,200.00 | 6,500.50 |
```

Actually the table consist of 10-12 categories, and the three(3) years column dynamically change when I select a particular year something like

```
| Category  | 2020 | 2019 | 2018 |
```

thanks guys.

Comment: Start by picking a charting library so you know the data structure needed. Mapping table row data is not difficult but you need to know the preferred structure first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by adding these scripts

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

and insert the codes along with AJAX. Something like this

```
$(function () {
                var chartdata={
                    table: 'highchart'
                }
                var chartype = {
                    type: 'column'
                }
                var chartitle = {
                    text: 'Revenue '+yy + ' vs ' + (yy-1) + ' vs ' + (yy-2)
                }
                var chartyaxis = {
                    allowDecimals: false,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Units'
                    }
                }
                var chartooltip = {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                            this.point.y + ' ' + this.point.name.toLowerCase();
                    }
                }
                $('#chartContainer2').highcharts({
                    data:chartdata,
                    chart:chartype,
                    title: chartitle,
                    yAxis: chartyaxis,
                    tooltip: chartooltip
                });
            });
```

It will only accept and reads numbers without comma(,)